# Loop through Item Template and save changes to database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, itemtemplate

Hoping someone can help.

We have a webpage we are pulling data from a database into bootstrap items and a drop down. The front end user is able to change the value in the dropdown.

However in the c# we are unsure how to take the changed drop down values, iterate through the item template and update the appropriate database table.

The code so far is:

```
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="getBacklog" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:smsConnection %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT projbacklog.Id, projbacklog.projectId, projbacklog.projectname, projbacklog.priority, projbacklog.refnum, projbacklog.userstory
                FROM projbacklog
                INNER JOIN projects ON projbacklog.projectId = projects.Id
                WHERE projbacklog.projectId = 9 ORDER BY projbacklog.priority ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                <!-- SQL data source to pull dropdown menu for priority level -->

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="priorityDropdown" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:smsConnection %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM projbacklog WHERE projbacklog.projectId = 9"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                <asp:Label ID="projectNameLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("projectname") %>'></asp:Label>

                <asp:ListView ID="backlog" runat="server" DataSourceID="getBacklog">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <br />
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">

                                <asp:Label ID="userStoryTxt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userstory") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                                 <asp:Label ID="refNum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("refnum") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="storyPriorityDrp" runat="server" DataSourceID="priorityDropdown" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("priority") %>' DataTextField="priority" DataValueField="priority">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

On the click of the button we want to save the new value back to the database. Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Addn the row id to into listview item

```
 <asp:hiddenfield id="projectId"
              Value='<%#Eval("projectId")%>' 
              runat="server"/>
```

Add an UpdateCommand

```
UpdateCommand="Update projbacklog SET priority=@priority WHERE projectId =@projectId"
```

Comment: Okay thanks, but how can I access the stored values from the drop down in the c# code?

Comment: storyPriorityDrp.SelectedItem.Value

Comment: We can't seem to access the StoryPriortyDrop value though - it doesn't seem to be accessible from the c#. We get the does not exist error.

Comment: instade of handle code, you can use Update Button
http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/105_EditUpdateDelete_and_Insert_in_ListView_Control.aspx